# opening pdf file on mobile app using ionic

Tags: pdf-generation, ionic-framework

I use Ionic framework for building mobile app. I call a webapi service,and it returns a byte array to me.(thi byte array is a pdf file that saved in db.) Now, I want to show this pdf file on my mobile application. How can I show a pdf file using ionic?
I read articles on net. But I can not achieve open pdf file. Can anyone give me idea ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What I did to achieve this was to send the PDF by email using the following plugin : https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer
Then, you will be able to open the PDF. I did not find a better solution with Ionic.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for reply. I want to ask one thing. As I understand, you send an email to some email address,then you open that mail and attach pdf file. DAm I right? Or I misunderstood you.

Comment: I mean that you can send an email with your pdf file attached to an email address. the plugin enables you to attach some Byte Array data ! So everything is done from your controller (you create your Byte Array data, and then create an email with the plugin in which you attach your data).